# How to pick First and Last number from String Swift

Tags: swift, numbers

i want to get First and Last number from dynamic string.

String could be any number like below.

**"1-3,28-30,55"** ==> **Output is 1 & 55**

**"104-105,131-132,157"** ==> **Output is 104 & 157**

**"188,192,194"** ==> **Output is 188 & 194**

**"202"** ==> **Output is 202 & 0**

**"204-206,208-212,215-220"** **Output is 204 & 220**

## OBJECT

```
class PalletRangeObject: NSObject {
    var start: Int = 0
    var end: Int = 0
    var strRange: String = ""
    
    init(start: Int, end: Int, range: String) {
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.strRange = range
    }
}
```

**For above achievement i have tried below code but in some cases it's not working.**

```
for i in 0..<self.arrPalletRange.count {
    let objPlRange = self.arrPalletRange[i]
    if !objPlRange.strRange.isEmpty {
        var nStart = 0
        var nEnd = 0
                                                    
        let pointsArr = objPlRange.strRange.components(separatedBy: ",")
        for i in 0..<pointsArr.count {
            let arr = pointsArr[i].components(separatedBy: "-")
            let newData = arr.map { Int($0)!}
            if newData.count == 1 {
                if nStart == 0 {
                    nStart = Int(newData.first ?? 0)
                    continue
                }
                nEnd = Int(newData.first ?? 0)
                continue
            }
            else {
                if nStart == 0 {
                    nStart = Int(newData.first ?? 0)
                    continue
                }
                nEnd = Int(newData.last ?? 0)
            }
        }
        objPlRange.start = nStart
        objPlRange.end = nEnd
    }
}
```

Can anyone please guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67703304/11690901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be that complicated. You seem to just want to get the first and last substring separated by either `,` or `-`.

You can use `components(separatedBy:)`

```
for i in 0..<self.arrPalletRange.count {
    let objPlRange = self.arrPalletRange[i]
    let allComponents = objPlRange.strRange.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet([",", "-"]))
    if let firstComponent = allComponents.first,
        let firstComponentInt = Int(firstComponent),
        let lastComponent = allComponents.last,
        let lastComponentInt = Int(lastComponentInt) {
        objPlRange.start = firstComponentInt
        objPlRange.end = lastComponentInt
    } else {
        // the string is empty, or the values are not valid integers
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can find the first and last index of a `-` or `,`, and cut the string at those positions. This avoids creating the array of all components, since you don't need most of them.

```
for i in 0..<self.arrPalletRange.count {
    let objPlRange = self.arrPalletRange[i]
    let firstIndex = objPlRange.strRange.firstIndex(where: { $0 == "-" || $0 == "," }) ?? objPlRange.strRange.endIndex
    let lastIndex = objPlRange.strRange.lastIndex(where: { $0 == "-" || $0 == "," }) ?? objPlRange.strRange.startIndex
    if let firstComponentInt = Int(objPlRange.strRange[..<firstIndex])
        let lastComponentInt = Int(lastComponentInt[lastIndex...]) {
        objPlRange.start = firstComponentInt
        objPlRange.end = lastComponentInt
    } else {
        // the string is empty, or the values are not valid integers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `firstIndex` and `lastIndex` to find non-numerical characters and then use `prefix` and `suffix` to extract the values.

Here is a function that returns the first and last int as a tuple

```
func firstAndLast(_ string: String) -> (Int, Int) {
    guard let start = string.firstIndex(where: { !$0.isNumber }) else {
        return string.isEmpty ? (0, 0) : (Int(string) ?? 0, 0)
    }
    
    guard let end = string.lastIndex(where: { !$0.isNumber }) else {
        return (0, 0)
    }
    
    return (Int(string.prefix(upTo: start)) ?? 0, Int(string.suffix(from: string.index(end, offsetBy: 1))) ?? 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple code that you can use to achieve that.

For first Number

```
func findFirst(number: String) -> String{
guard number != "" else {return ""}
var firstNumber = ""
for i in number{
    if i.isNumber{
        firstNumber.append(i)
    }else{
        return firstNumber
    }
}
return firstNumber
}
```

This is for the second number

```
func findLast(number: String) -> String{
guard number != "" else {return ""}
var firstNumber = ""
for i in number.reversed(){
    if i.isNumber{
        firstNumber.append(i)
    }else{
        return firstNumber
    }
}
return firstNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand your question properly, but as per my understanding here is the simplest code I can give you

```
let string = "2A4-206,208-212,215-220"
let numbers = string.components(separatedBy: [",","-"]).filter({ string in
    if let _ = Int(string) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
})

if numbers.count == 0 {
    print("Start: 0, End: 0")
} else if let first = Int(numbers.first ?? ""), numbers.count == 1 {
    print("Start: \(first), End: 0")
} else if let first = Int(numbers.first ?? ""), let last = Int(numbers.last ?? "") {
    print("Start: \(first), End: \(last)")
}
```

You can add this code in function and replace print statement with return block